# Passar variável oculta em redirecionamento de página php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, aplicação-web, login, crud

Estrou fazendo um trabalho e preciso que ao termino da minha autenticação na página de login, o php redirecione pro index junto com uma variável.
No login eu fiz um select onde me retornou o nickname do usuário, agora preciso enviar esse nickname para a index a fim de fazer outras consultas lá a partir deste nick. como posso fazer isso sem que fique exposto na url ou no código-fonte?.

Sou novo em web, não sei como fazer isso.

Tinha feito este código:

```
if(isset($_POST['submeter'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['senha'];
        $pass = hash('sha256', $pass);
        $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT loginUsuario FROM usuario WHERE email =? and senhaUsuario=?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss',$email,$pass);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows <=0){
            echo "<h3 id='erro'>E-mail ou senha incorretos!</h3>";
        }else{
            $result= $stmt->bind_result($loginUsuario);
            $stmt->fetch(); 
            setcookie("login",$email);
            header("location: index.php"); //passar $loginUsuario junto de alguma forma.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você utilizou um cookie `setcookie("login",$email);` para guardar essa informação não é melhor recuperar o cookie? tipo `$_COOKIE['login']` ? não sei se é a melhor forma, foi baseado no seu código.

Comment: este comando de cookie eu vi na internet, não sei bem utiliza-lo. Pode me explicar quais parâmetros eu coloco dentro e onde este cookie fica "armazenado"? E como recuperar ele na outra pagina.

Comment: Cookie fica na maquina do cliente, no navegador e você pode recuperar na página index por exemplo com o comando `echo $_COOKIE['login'];`.

Comment: podes usar também session.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de session? Não sei a respeito da segurança ao usar cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar também session.

Obs:    `session_start();` é obrigatório e deve ser o primeiro elemento da sua página, antes de qualquer entrada html

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
 ................
 ................
 if(isset($_POST['submeter'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['senha'];
    $pass = hash('sha256', $pass);
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT loginUsuario FROM usuario WHERE email =? and senhaUsuario=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss',$email,$pass);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows <=0){
        echo "<h3 id='erro'>E-mail ou senha incorretos!</h3>";
    }else{
        $result= $stmt->bind_result($loginUsuario);
        $stmt->fetch(); 
        setcookie("login",$email);

        //criando a session
        $_SESSION["login"]=$email;            

        header("location: index.php"); //passar $loginUsuario junto de alguma forma.
    }
}
```

Na index

```
<?php 
session_start();
$login=$_SESSION["login"];

//caso queira usar o cookie
//$login=$_COOKIE['login'];
```

Comment: Obrigado. Chegando em casa faço os testes. Tem alguma das duas soluções com melhor desempenho/segurança para eu optar? Poderia usar mais de um session para passar mais variáveis?

Comment: sim, quantas sessions forem necessárias

Comment: cookies tem aquele papo de o javascript estar desabilitado e coisa e tal

Comment: E pra que serve o session_start? Qual a diferença se não usar? Eu não o implementei no código.

Comment: se não usar não vai funcionar

Comment: o session_start() é usado qd vc tem uma sessão criada e quer propagar a informações da sessão...
uma sessão serve pra guardar valores numa variável, passando de uma página para outra seus valores "automaticamente".  veja mais em http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php

Comment: Okay. Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.